# Stuck at 4 dots

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I have often encountered an issue that my machine gets stuck at the 4 dots on the boot screen. In the past I have simply hard powered down and powered up again and this seems to solve the issue.

Today, however, it hasn't. I have done some preliminary research and it seems to be a graphic card issue that requires me to access the GRUB menu.

But I cannot access it. If I try to use SHIFT (both held down and pressing repeatedly) the machine proceeds as if nothing has happened. If I press ESCAPE (both held down and pressing repeatedly) I get a completely black screen with no words on an underscore.

I am currently using a bootable USB drive to access the internet as I cannot use my machine otherwise.

Hardware info:
Toshiba Satellite L70D-A, 64 bit Notebook with 16GB RAM

```
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Insyde Corp.
      version: 1.30
      date: 09/06/2013
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 4MiB

*-cpu: AMD A10-5750M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics       
      version: AMD A10-5750M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
      size: 1488MHz
      capacity: 2500MHz
      clock: 100MHz
```

I am grateful for any advice.

The result of the command `ls -al /boot` is:

```
total 297188
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Mar  9 07:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Mar  9 07:31 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257683 Jan 13 15:11 config-5.13.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257734 Jan 19 03:16 config-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257734 Feb  7 06:01 config-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257734 Mar  6 23:40 config-5.13.0-35-generic
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Mar  9 07:36 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Mar  9 07:34 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.13.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 59481477 Mar  6 14:17 initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 59555306 Mar  6 14:18 initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 59563204 Mar  8 18:35 initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 59563533 Mar  9 07:35 initrd.img-5.13.0-35-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Mar  9 07:34 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5958177 Jan 13 15:11 System.map-5.13.0-27-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5959931 Jan 19 03:16 System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5960334 Feb  7 06:01 System.map-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5960381 Mar  6 23:40 System.map-5.13.0-35-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Mar  9 07:34 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-35-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10161824 Jan 13 15:50 vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10170592 Jan 19 05:43 vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10171040 Feb  7 06:03 vmlinuz-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10171296 Mar  7 00:09 vmlinuz-5.13.0-35-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Mar  9 07:34 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-30-generic
```

Comment: If you are using a bootable USB device, then you should be able to access the logs on the main drive. Could you take a look at the `boot.log` files as well as `syslog` (in `/var/log`) to see if there is a point where the system constantly locks up? This will confirm whether it's a graphics adapter issue or not. Could you also include some hardware details for your machine? This will make it more likely that someone can offer a solution 

Comment: When you abruptly cut the power, this can sometimes cause problems in unpredictable ways. It's possible that your forced shutdowns added new problems to your existing problem. If it were me, I would probably reinstall. You can use the live session to access any data in case your backups are not up-to-date

Comment: A simmilar issue had happened to me, if you have an Nvidia card, try deleting the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file

Comment: I can access the Boot.log as well as the syslog. Although I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for, I believe these messages are of significance:

 ubuntu kernel: do_IRQ: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
 ubuntu kernel: do_IRQ: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
 ubuntu kernel: do_IRQ: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
 ubuntu kernel: Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs... 
 ubuntu kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First check your file system:**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Boot to the GRUB menu and choose Recovery Mode, Root access.

**At the # prompt:**

`sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # to remount the disk r/w

<strike>`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` # to rebuild the ram disk</strike>

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.13.0-30-generic`

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.13.0-35-generic`

---

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU.

**Disable Wayland on login screen:**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

or

`sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit` or `pico`. Then type `reboot`.

Comment: I tried everything you said but I still get the same result - stuck at the 4 dots

Comment: @Kritter At the GRUB menu, try booting to an older kernel, and see if it boots. Report back.

Comment: @Kritter Also show me `grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, and `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: I booted to an older kernel, specifically 5.13.0.27-generic and it worked. In other words, I was able to log inot my machine as normal. However, the filesystem was read-only so I was not able to launch Firefox, mount external drives etc.

The command
`grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
produced
`WaylandEnable=false`

The command `la -al /boot`
produced a result that is too long to paste into a comment

Comment: I'll try using more than one comment:  
total 5400  
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      60 Jul 31  2020 .  
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     260 Mar  9 04:22 ..  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  237773 Jul  9  2020 config-5.4.0-42-generic
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      60 Mar  9 04:22 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      27 Jul 31  2020 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      27 Jul 31  2020 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  182704 Feb 13  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  184380 Feb 13  2020 memtest86+.elf

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  184884 Feb 13  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root 4738430 Jul  9  2020 System.map-5.4.0-42-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jul 31  2020 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jul 31  2020 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic

Comment: @Kritter As you discovered, comments aren't the right place for lengthy command output. What's there is incomplete, and it's awful difficult to read. Please redo the `ls -al /boot` command, copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, paste the output, select the pasted text, then click the {} to change it to a human-readable format. Thanks!

Comment: @Kritter Regarding read-only disk... you did the `fsck`, yes?

Comment: my sincere apologies for the confusing posts. I have posted the contents of `ls -al /boot` to the original question. Regarding the `fsck` command - I did not do that. However, I just tried the old kernel again and I got the BusyBox built-in shell where I used the `fsck` command and it worked. I am now writing to you via the old kernel on my machine. What do you recommend as next steps? Should I attempt to repair the old kernel or continue using the old one? I very much appreciate your help

Comment: @Kritter I only see one kernel referenced in /boot. /boot isn't complete. I don't understand *"attempt to repair the old kernel or continue using the old one"*. You're missing your ram disk file initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic, and vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic, so I don't know how you're even booting. Since you originally didn't do my `fsck`, I assume that you also didn't do my `update-initramfs` command, true?

Comment: Just to clarify - I did run the `fsck` command whilst using the Ubuntu Live USB. I did not run it after that. I just re-ran command `ls -al /boot` command whilst using the old kernel and I have posted the longer results into the original question. I did try the `update-initramfs` command at the point you said ie. GRUB menu -> Recovery mode -> root access. When I said _"attempt to repair the old kernel or continue using the old one"_ I was just trying to clarify what I meant by "next steps".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134658/discussion-between-heynnema-and-kritter).